# angular 5 ng build --base-href "./" generates inline.bundle.js,inline.bundle.js.map,main.bundle.js,main.bundle.js.map

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

what is the difference between main.bundle.jsp, main.bundle.js.map
why  angular is generating .map for all the files like main.bundle.js.map,polyfills.bundle.js.map styles.bundle.js.map,vendor.bundle.js.map

Answer (score 0):

These are sourcemap files to aid in debugging. You can learn more about sourcemaps here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps

Comment: Is this optional ? I mean where can we specify angular to generate or not to generate sourcemap files

Comment: It is on by default when not in AOT mode. There is a flag to turn it off if you want to. Refer to the docs on this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build